# Setting the default installation location for pip

Tags: ubuntu, disk-space, default-settings, pip, ubuntu-15.10

I'm working on a computer with *extremely* limited internal storage, so I want to set up pip and my Python environment so that new packages are installed to an SD card (which is going to be inside the machine all the time anyway) by default.

Does pip provide this kind of functionality?

Comment: which OS do you use?

Comment: @magicandre1981 This is on Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat alternative approach could be virtualenv, like this:

```
virtualenv path/to/your/storage/venv
```

then

```
source path/to/your/storage/venv/bin/activate
```

This last command transports you to your virtual environment, and while in there, anything installed via `pip` will get installed in that directory, which can be on other device.
I would prefer this approach, because there's very little manual configuring required, but you would need to install virtualenv (it's about 2MB).

Answer (score 0):

You should change your pip.conf file.

The question to change the default installation directory was answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24175174

Have you tried this?